# Merge 2 DateTime vars into one in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 DateTime variables.

```
One is: DateTime date //this format is yyyymmdd
Second is: DateTime time // this format is hhmmtt  (hour:min:tt)
```

How can I combine these 2 together? generate one DateTime variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var output = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day,
                          time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

This only works for the two dates you listed, though, where one is the date and one is the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert one of the DateTimes to a `TimeSpan` and add it to the second `DateTime`. Take the time-only `DateTime`. You can use its `GetTicks` method and pass it to a\the `TimeSpan` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime day; //assumed set with the correct date
DateTime time; //assumed set with the relevant hour, minute, second

DateTime all = day.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second));
```

Comment: You should be able to just use `time.TimeOfDay` instead of creating a `TimeSpan` object like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012,12,04);
DateTime time = new DateTime(1,1,1,11,20,30);
DateTime combined = date.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.Parse(time.ToShortTimeString()).TotalSeconds);

Console.WriteLine(date);
Console.WriteLine(time);
Console.WriteLine(combined);

04.12.2012 00:00:00
01.01.0001 11:20:30
04.12.2012 11:20:00
```